# Pattern for file path

Tags: r

I try to use this commands:

```
path <- "C:/Users/cfees/My Box Files/Fitness/"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv")
```

I would like to take files which are csv and start with a name "myfile_"

I try this:

```
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern=c("myfile_","*.csv"))
```

but it is empty value. How can I write it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `".+"` to `"myfile"` to say one or more any character. Be carefull the dot need to be escaped with `\\`, if not it means any character

```
list.files(path=path, pattern="myfile_.+\\.csv")
```

should work

Comment: Actually,  you need \\.    not \.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.files(path=path, pattern="myfile_.*csv$")
```